# NodeJSもしくはPythonからのSIP通話発信

Tags: python, node.js, kotlin

NodeJSもしくはPythonのプログラムからのSIP通話発信を行いたいのですが方法がわからず教えていただきたいです。

・ PBXサーバー「Asterisk」をAWSのEC2上に構築をしております。
・ Asteriskで払い出したSIP情報を設定し、モバイル端末同士で通話ができることは確認しました。
・ 以前Kotlinで実装をした際は「android.net.sip」を使いましたので同じ様な方法を探しています。

Comment: こんな記事があるようです。[how to writing SIP client in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56007746/9014308), [Python SIP library closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1286875/9014308), [SIP SIMPLE Client SDK](https://sipsimpleclient.org/), [AGProjects/python-sipsimple](https://github.com/AGProjects/python-sipsimple)

Comment: Node.js系だとこれらでしょうか。[How to make a SIP call through nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57532832/9014308), [jsSIP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jssip), [SIP.js](https://sipjs.com/), [SIP通話を発信する - Twillio](https://jp.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-making-calls)